# official github windows command line client

Tags: windows, git, github

Does GitHub offer a Windows command line client any more? I remember using one a few years ago but https://desktop.github.com/ is all I can find on their website and it looks like a GUI only tool.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GitHub doesn't have their own command client for Windows any more (or at least not one that they package up and advertise on their website).

https://gitforwindows.org/ seems to be the closest thing as out of the (as of August 2019) six maintainers, two work for GitHub and two work for Microsoft: https://github.com/orgs/git-for-windows/people
It's also the version of Git available on Git's website at https://git-scm.com/